# I can not see the icon in notifications in packaged app for chrome

Tags: google-chrome, notifications, google-chrome-app

I am trying to show a notification using a packaged app for Chrome, but I can not see the icon I choose, I can see the text but not the icon, I am using this:

```
window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(
      'icon.png', 'Push Message',
      "Push message for you! " );
```

Also I have tried with the Rich Notifications:

```
chrome.notifications.create("1", { iconUrl: "icon.png", 
    title: "Hello", message: "There.", type: "basic" }, 
    function () {});
```

But in both I can not see the icon, I am using Arch Linux and Chrome version 29 beta and Chromium 29(not beta), but only I cant see the icon, any help is welcome.

Thank you

Comment: We don't know where the icon is, either. Can you tell us?

Comment: File layout would be helpful. Also, have you compared your code to working samples like Notifications Galore? (search for it, can't link to it from phone)

Comment: The icon is in the same folder where is the manifest.json and the other javascript files of the app, my icon is a .png file, do you need I put all the code of the file? or only a specific section? I mean the code I put in the first part is from my file, do you need some more? please tell me.